# log4j2 Web Lookup not working

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, log4j2

We have Spring java-based web deployments which use log4j2.xml for logging messages to files, etc.

We now need to update our log4j2.xml configs in order to be able to do a ${web:contextPath} web lookup inside them so that we can use a deployment's context name as part of the log file's name which the loggers log messages to. However, when we deploy the apps, the log4j2 configurations fail to recognise any web lookup related stuff. The file created to log messages to is simply created with the name `${web` and no messages are actually logged in them.

I have read various docs online related to log4j2 web lookups when running in 3.0 servlets but I still can't see what the problem might be in our configurations. And I don't know what to look for in the log4j's trace logs in order to see what it is that we are missing.

Our Stack:

`Windows and Linux OSes
Java 8
Tomcat 7.0.5x
log4j-xxx 2.2 (log4j-api, log4j-core, log4j-slf4j-impl, log4j-jcl, log4j-web all in classpath)`

Any help on how to get web lookups to work is much appreciated.

Cheers,
PM

Comment: I've got the web lookup to work but I have questions... I had to make two modifications: 1) I had to remove `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.2` jar from classpath (but I don't know why? We need this facade for when using 3rd party jars that don't natively work with log4j2, right!?). 2) I had to include a `<display-name>name_here</display-name>` in the deployment's web.xml (I read in another post that the display name should not be enforced and that it was a bug - but still not fixed in Tomcat 7.0.59?). Can anyone comment on these?

Comment: Looking at the log4j mailing list, this issue has been resolved. Would you mind sharing the answer here?

Comment: Hi @RemkoPopma, I can certainly do that - unless one of you good peeps would like to provide the answer so that you can get the SO points, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Spring 4 java annotation based web application, it is possible to have `log4j-slf4j-impl` jar in the classpath and still do a `log4j2` web lookup by having your web initialization class extend `Log4jServletContainerInitializer` and calling `super.onStartup()` on it.

Example:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class WebInitialiser extends Log4jServletContainerInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {

        super.onStartup(null, servletContext);

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class, IntegrationConfig.class,
                JmsConfig.class, JmxConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }

}
```

Note however that you still seem to need to have your `web.xml` include a `<display-name>` node in order for `log4j2` web lookups to work on a `Tomcat 7.0.5x` container.

For more detail on all this, see the answers that I got in the log4j user mailing list thread:

[log4j2 web lookup questions](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201504.mbox/%3CCAGivfLzVDxbNhmfjzpcGcdcsRTmDuJksjD3YqFHaxk62qtOWBA%40mail.gmail.com%3E)

Cheers,
PM.

Comment: my web lookup was working on windows. I mean when I ran my application locally on windows then `${web:rootDir}` was resolving. I have `log4j-slf4j-impl` in my classpath too. But when I deploy my application on Linux then I got the error that `${web:rootDir} unable to resolve`. By your solution it starts working on Linux too. Thanks :)