# log4j 2.5 Web Lookup not working

Tags: java, spring, logging, tomcat7, log4j2

I have previously asked the question here on stackoverflow on how to get web lookups to work in log4j2 (See [log4j2 Web Lookup not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558291/log4j2-web-lookup-not-working)). Eventually, the question was answered and all was fine. Now, when I got it working, the web apps were all `Spring 4` based apps using `log4j 2.2` jars running on `Tomcat 5.0.57` containers.

Now however, we have almost the same setup as before (i.e `Spring 4` on `Tomcat 5.0.57` containers) with the exception that, the log4j jars have now been updated to `log4j v2.5` jars. With log4j v2.5 jars the web lookups are still working when deployed on Windows Tomcat 5.0.57 containers but, NO LONGER on linux Tomcat 5.0.57 containers.

On our linux Tomcat containers the log files are now being created as: `${web:contextPath}.log` instead of actually replacing the lookup variable with the deployment's context path name.

What has changed since log4j v2.2 that may cause web lookups to stop working?

Comment: UPDATE: The reason it worked before and not now is not due to log4j 2 version differences. Before, all log4j 2 jars were inside the WAR file to be deployed. Whereas now, the log4j 2 jars are all in the tomcat's lib folder (except log4j-web jar which is still inside the WAR file). It seems that the web lookup only works on a linux Tomcat container when all the log4j jars are inside the WAR itself? Is this a log4j requirement?

Comment: Well, `${web:contextPath}` is only meaningful in a web application. From lib, which context would you want to use?

Comment: @RemkoPopma, I thought that the common log4j jars could be kept in the tomcat lib folder (except for log4j-web jar which would still sit inside each WAR file). Then a WAR deployment would work under its own context and therefore the deployment log4j2.xml's `${web:contextPath}` would resolve to the deployment's context name okay. This works okay on Windows Tomcat but not linux Tomcat. Anyway, are you saying that all log4j jars MUST always be provided inside a WAR file and not provided within Tomcat's lib folder? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: To be honest, better to ask this on the log4j-user list or file a JIRA to get input from the whole community.